# Can't log in. Password submitted not matching password stored in DB. - PHP, Password_hash

Tags: php, password-hash

I have added the `password_hash` PHP function to my registration page, where users create accounts and store passwords. I applied the same `password_hash` line of code in the registration form. The data is saved in the database, but when I try to log in, the password submitted isn't matching the password stored. I also tried the `password_verify` function, which I read in the PHP manual, but nothing works. I really don't know what else to do, after trying and trying, so if anybody has an advice, I'd appreciated it.

P.S. I'm currently using PHP version 5.6.25.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("PHP_Includes/db.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['e']);
    $p = password_hash($_POST['p'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost' => 15]);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        } else {
            // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS 
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

login() function:

```
function login(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if(e == "" || p == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt using `password_verify()`? That's what you need to use. `password_hash()` will give you different results each time it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of how `password_hash()` works is a bit off. Unlike using `sha1()` or `md5()` (both of which you should avoid for storing passwords!), the `password_hash()` doesn't return the same string for every time it's called, even for the same string.

For example:

```
var_dump(password_hash("hello_world", PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
var_dump(password_hash("hello_world", PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

would output (for example, the strings returned by `password_hash()` varies for each time its called)

```
string(60) "$2y$10$Da2HG0dcvfI.3qBivR8Mpu9U5S06PBZ3415lDEh3EcDZ/fELZzHgC"
string(60) "$2y$10$zL6745UkPEvZWS5w1Keco.IKi7ssl.PqldGxucDYHaJW3vgCc366a"
```

Notice that they are different, even when the function is called twice on the *same* value? This means, that you cannot compare the stored password against `$p = password_hash($_POST['p'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost' => 15]);` like you are currently doing, because the `password_hash()` function returns a different string every time - you need to use the function `password_verify()` to verify the password, like below

```
$p = $_POST['p'];

if (password_verify($p, $fromDataBase)) {
    // Valid password!
}
```

So instead of...

```
$p = password_hash($_POST['p'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost' => 15]);
```

you want

```
$p = $_POST['p'];
```

and instead of...

```
if($p != $db_pass_str){
```

you want

```
if (!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)) {
```

---

And two notes on security:

1. You are not using prepared statements, which you **REALLY** should! See a link for `mysqli_prepare()` below. You should treat all your user-input as dangerous, and therefor use prepared statements for all SQL queries that accepts user-input. (When using prepared statements, you don't want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` - use one or the other, most preferably prepared statements!)
2. You are storing a password in a session - this is highly discouraged, as sessions can be "hijacked".

---

Readingmaterial:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: First of all, wow!! Thank you so much for your reply. It's like the best reply I've ever gotten! Thank you! I made the changes as you suggested, however after making the changes, my page stopped loading. The server is fine, and other pages are fine, but that one page with the code isn't working anymore. After investigating what happened, the line of code `if (!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)` is the problem. Not sure what to make of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, yes - that's my bad, I made a typo when typing up the answer. It should be like `if (!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)) {` (there's a missing `)` after the `if` causing syntax errors). I'll update the answer too!

Comment: Ahhh!! I should have seen that! I'm really tired, so that's my excuse. :D Btw, I tried the code and it works!! Just today I started to learn about the password_hash function and I'm thankful that you brought some things to my attention. I'm teaching myself, so your advice is appreciated. Thanks again for your help!! :D :D

Comment: Happy to have been of help! Glad you sorted it out :-) good luck with your continued programming and learning ;-)